# Python skipping else statement when no elifs match (animated gif of debug step through included)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm at a loss for how to debug this one. The gif is pretty self explanatory. I've got nearly identical if/elif/else statements that work fine.

[image]

Comment: Here's a functionally identical chunk of test code working fine.
https://gifyu.com/image/nbBM

Comment: Ok, through a lot of commenting out of lines, I found the issue, but I have no idea why. If I comment out game_state = GameStates.sw_confirm, the else works as expected. This is an enum, and it is properly defined and imported. Furthermore, I use these all over with no trouble. I've gone so far as to retype the line, and it still errors. Further testing shows that setting the gamestate to anything, at any point under the elif/else at 652, causes this behavior. I'm completely at a loss as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I retyped the entire else statement at 652, and it works. My only guess is that there was a non-printing character in there somewhere monkeying things up. Very weird.